# Add hyperlink inside a cell event in itext

Tags: java, itext

I am writing a cell event for a PDF cell.I need to write some text and append a **hyperlink** to that text.
Every thing is working fine but hyperlink is not showing and not clickable.
I am using **itext5**.

Note : My requirement is to write the code inside a cell event, not in normal cell(searched in internate, all examples are for normal cell).

```
private static class AddHyperLink implements PdfPCellEvent {

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {

        Paragraph mainPragraph = new Paragraph();
        Chunk descCk = new Chunk("This is "), descFont);

        mainPragraph.add(descCk);
        Chunk orgDiscriptionMore = new Chunk("HyperLink");
        orgDiscriptionMore.setAnchor("http:/www.google.com");
        mainPragraph.add(orgDiscriptionMore);

        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);

        ct.setSimpleColumn(position);
        ct.addElement(mainPragraph);

        ct.go();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"My requirement is to write the code inside a cell event, not in normal cell"* - then you should fix the requirement. For a cell event listener to be triggered, you need a cell with that listener registered. And for a large enough cell the visible text should be added to the original cell, not a cell listener.

Comment: @mkl requirement is from client, I can't fix the requirement.

Comment: Having applied the obvious corrections to make your code *compilable* I could observe that your code does work. It merely (obviously) needs to be assigned to a large enough cell, cf. my answer.

Comment: Did my answer solve the issue? If it does, please accept the answer. If it doesn't, please clarify which issues still remain.

Comment: No , Still the hyperlink is not working

Comment: In that case please indicate, ***a*** which iText version exactly do you use? And ***b*** which PDF viewer in which version do you use exactly? I'm using the current iText 5.5.13 and the current Adobe Acrobat Reader DC version 2018.011.20055. And as described in my answer the code does work. In particular the link was there all along, and it was clickable; I just added the fact to the answer that you of course have to use a valid target URL which your code does not.

Comment: I added valid URL.I'm using the current iText 5.5.13 and opening PDF in Acrobat Reader DC, Acrobat Reader Pro and all browser.Still i am not able to click.On mouse hover also the url is not visible.

Comment: Please share an example result PDF of your code.

Answer (score 0):

### In short

Essentially your code works for me, you merely need to give it a large enough cell to work in!

### In detail

#### Correcting the obvious errors

The line

```
Chunk descCk = new Chunk("This is "), descFont);
```

obviously is wrong, opening and closing brackets don't match. And as you did not provide a `descFont` anywhere, I simply dropped it and reduced the line to

```
Chunk descCk = new Chunk("This is ");
```

The line

```
ct.go();
```

obviously causes a compile error as that method is declared as `throws DocumentException`. I simply enveloped it in a `try {} catch() {}`:

```
try {
    ct.go();
} catch (DocumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now your class is compilable...

*([Cf. the inner class `AddHyperLink` in the `CreateLink` test](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/annotate/CreateLink.java#L206))*

Ah, and obviously one other detail needs to be fixed:

```
orgDiscriptionMore.setAnchor("http:/www.google.com");
```

The URL is invalid, to make it work, use a valid URL:

```
orgDiscriptionMore.setAnchor("http://www.google.com");
```

#### Providing a large enough cell

To verify that the listener works, we merely need a table with a cell that's large enough for the text you want to add, e.g.

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(...);
image.scaleToFit(110,110);

Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "link-in-cell-event.pdf")));
writer.setCompressionLevel(0);
doc.open();

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(image);
cell.setCellEvent(new AddHyperLink());

table.addCell(cell);
doc.add(table);

doc.close();
```

*([CreateLink](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/annotate/CreateLink.java#L175) test `testCreateLinkInCellEvent`)*

The result with my example image:

[image: screen shot]

Thus, it works all right.